# How to set fragment above bottom navigation view with xml?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to show a fragment host above bottom navigation view. But bottom nav view takes a portion of the fragment host. I tried solutions of other SO answers but it still not solving the problem.
I used both Relative layout with 'layout_above' attribute and constraint layout with realted attributes to keep the fragment above bottom nav view. But the fragment show the text view is still cut off by bottom nav view.

Heres the xml codes I tried:
With relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

with constaint layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How do I set the fragment host above bottom navigation view with xml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there's still some empty space on the top of the fragment and after the bottom of the title bar. Do you know why and how to remove this empty space?

Comment: @Rifat can you share some screenshots for better understanding ?

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil I have added a picture with color codes added on Erwin Kurniawan's solution to show the unwanted empty space. It looks like a hidden navigation bar space is left there.

Answer (score 6):

Replace the paddingTop by 0dp value, that solved it for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" <!-- Delete this line -->

    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" <!-- If you have BottomNavigationView, add this line, so it doesn't overlap your list -->
>
```

Comment: Incorrect. while it does solve the top part, if your content is very long like a list, it gets cut off because the BottomNavigationView overlaps in front of it.

Comment: You can add `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"`, I'm working with long lists too :)